# Ajax Django file preview

Tags: python, django, ajax

I want to upload a xlsx file through a simple html form and pass some values for a Django function to process. 
Since I have no knowledge of Ajax or any idea to do the following I am seeking your help.

> I want to upload the file and pass some values. After I submit the
>   file/values I want a page to load which would have a set of output
>   values as a preview of sorts. I've heard that Ajax is the way but I
>   have no idea. Please help me either write it or give me a step by step
>   guide for it. p.s I have no JS knowledge.

```
<center>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action ='File/'>
    {% csrf_token %}<br><br>


Select a file:   <input type="file" name="vendorfile"><br>
Start: <input type="text" name="start_value" ><br>
Dest: <input type="text" name="dest_col" ><br>
Num: <input type="text" name="num_col" ><br>
Rate: <input type="text" name="rate_col" ><br>
<button  type="submit" >Preview</button>

</form>

</center>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge'/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


{% for k,v in _empty %}
{% for x,y in v %}
{{ k }}::<br>
{{ x }}::<br>
{{ y }}::
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

```
url(r'^(?i)File/$', FileView.as_view(), name='File-Page'),

    url(r'^(?i)xls/$',
        views.xlsparser, name='XLS'),
```

```
def xlsparser(request):
    template_name = 'LCR\output.html'
    sheet_name    = request.POST.get('sheet_name')
    start_value   = request.POST.get('start_value')
    end_value     = 40 #request.POST.get('end_value')
    dest_value    = request.POST.get('dest_col')
    num_value     = request.POST.get('num_col')
    rate_value    = request.POST.get('rate_col')
    file = request.FILES('vendorfile')
    book          = xlrd.open_workbook(file)


    # book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
    _empty = {}

    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    for i in range(start_value, end_value):
        cell_key = sheet.cell(i, key_line).value
        cell_value = sheet.cell(i,value_line).value
        cell_rate = sheet.cell(i,rate_line).value

        _empty[cell_key] = [(cell_value,cell_rate)]

    return render(request, template_name, _empty)




class FileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "LCR\LCRupload.html"
```

Comment: Since you don't have experience with ajax, and you say yourself the user first fills in a form to submit a file, then views a page with a summary of what was uploaded, **don't use ajax**. Just return a new page with the preview when the file is uploaded. Add ajax later if you think it's required. But for now, it just makes everything more complex.

Comment: I don't want to save the file in the database.  I want the file to be stored in the system memory until the process is executed.
As a run time program

Comment: But an ajax request is just an HTTP request. At the end of it, any variables/processing you did is cleared like with a 'normal' HTTP request When the user then submits the form, the file is submitted again, a new request is made and you have no access to previous variables.

Comment: That's the idea. each user has a different set of variables. The file has no need to be saved.

Comment: So what's the problem with your current code? I'm not saying you need to save the file. You're not describing anything that requires ajax in your question.

Comment: It's rendering an empty page.

Comment: that's probably because you're submitting your form to "File/" (which is the template view) instead of submitting your form to the parser view. Change your `action` parameter to "xls/" or better yet to `{% url "XLS" %}`.

Comment: please edit my question or write it here